# Unable to add Postgres user to existing readonly role

Tags: postgresql

I'm attempting to add a new user "svcUatOlapEdw" to an existing RHEL 7 server running PSQL 9.4.

Using inet authentication (after su - postgres) and working from a PSQL prompt as follows:

```
-bash-4.2$ psql
psql (9.4.6)
Type "help" for help.
postgres=#
```

The commands I successfully executed were:

```
CREATE USER svcUatOlapEdw
GRANT readonly to svcUatOlapEdw
```

However, when attempting to connect from a client, I'm getting:

```
-bash-4.1$ psql -h myserver -d postgres -U svcUatOlapEdw -W
Password for user svcUatOlapEdw:
psql: FATAL:  role "svcUatOlapEdw" does not exist
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here - any help would be appreciated.

Additionally, I also tried:

```
CREATE ROLE svcUatOlapEdw
```

which didn't resolve the issue either.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unquoted identifiers are [folded to lower case](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) in Postgres. So `CREATE USER svcUatOlapEdw` creates a user with the name `svcuatolapedw`. Any identifier you pass through SQL statements is also folded to lower case, that's why `GRANT readonly to svcUatOlapEdw` works (it's executed as `GRANT readonly to svcuatolapedw`).

However, `psql` passes the user name "as-is" and tries to log on with a user named `"svcUatOlapEdw"`. You need to pass the username in lower case:

```
psql -h myserver -d postgres -U svcuatolapedw -W
```

**Edit**

If you want to create a user with upper/lower case name you have to use a quoted identifier:

```
CREATE USER "svcUatOlapEdw";
GRANT readonly to "svcUatOlapEdw";
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the hint.  The problem I have here is that the account is served via SSSD (with AD on the backend), and there is no "lowercase" version of that POSIX account:

$ id svcuatolapedw
id: svcuatolapedw: no such user

$ id svcUatOlapEdw
uid=22421(svcUatOlapEdw) gid=30001(netuser) groups=30001(netuser)

I therefore tried quoting as follows:

    # CREATE USER 'svcUatOlapEdw'
    # GRANT readonly to 'svcUatOlapEdw'
    # CREATE ROLE 'svcUatOlapEdw'

But I’m still running into the same issue. Do I need to delete the ‘lowercase’ versions that PSQL now knows about first ?

Comment: @PatrickRynhart: you need double quotes `"` not single quotes to create a [quoted identifier](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

Comment: Thanks so much!  I had to drop the lowercase version (listing users using \du showed that an uppercase equivalent wasn't being created).  After doing that all was well.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

```
 CREATE ROLE  read_only_user WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'StrongPass123123123' NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION VALID UNTIL 'infinity';
    GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE "yourdatabase" TO read_only_user;
    GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO read_only_user;
    GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO read_only_user;
    GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO read_only_user;
```

It works on Psql 14, Ubuntu 18